# Linking installed game with steam

Tags: steam, medieval-2-total-war

Medieval total war 2 is already installed on my pc, if I look in steam it is there and it only says "install"

Is there anyway of making steam recognise that its installed already and link them or do I have to wait 8 hours for it to download and install on steam?

Thank you

EDIT: The reason I wish to link the two is so I can get steam to auto update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try doing that:

1. Go to [Your Steam folder]\SteamApps\common\ and create a folder there by the name of "Medieval II Total War" (without quotes, obviously).
2. Put everything from standalone installation folder to this newly created one.
3. Start installing Medieval through Steam. It should find all the resources. It will download something however (whatever different in Steam version comparing to standalone one) though it should be way less than downloading the whole game.

Comment: Am going to accept this, however its still downloading 10 gig of file for some reason, it did discover so gonna see how it goes and can check back with an update

Comment: Sometimes it displays as it is downloading but it actually is not (just rediscovering the file), so download will finish faster than it should and you're good to go. This bug occured in Steam when I tried this method, though it was some time ago.

Comment: If you never installed the game before on Steam, it won't have the necessary .ACF file, and will redownload the whole game.

Comment: When I did this trick with Civ4 (and I have never installed it through Steam before) it only redownloaded couple hundred of megs.